# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key distanceLabel

Tags: swift, storyboard

I've been getting this error, and can't figure out where the problem is:

> This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key distanceLabel.

Here is some code related to `distanceLabel`:

```swift
import UIKit

class PastRunTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var durationLabel: UILabel!


  var pastrun: Run!{
    didSet{
      configure()
    }
  }

  private func configure(){
//    guard let pr = pastrun
//    else {
//      return
//    }
    let pr = pastrun!
    let dateRun = FormatDisplay.date(pr.timestamp)
    timeLabel.text = "\(dateRun)"
    //print("wfewfdsfw \(pr.timestamp)    \(pr.distance)   \(pr.duration)")
    //let dis:String = String(format: "%03x", pr.distance)
    distanceLabel.text = "Distance: \(String(format:"%.3f",pr.distance)) miles"
    durationLabel.text = "Duration: \(pr.duration) min"
    accessoryType = .none
    selectionStyle = .none

  }

}
```

Here is the screenshot of the storyboard (I can't find any issue on connecting):

[image]

I checked similar questions and tried to reconnect the outlets many times, but it just did not work.

Comment: Did you right click on the view controller's "settings" button (looks like an orange circle with a white square on top) at the top of the view controller in the storyboard? From here, you should be able to see all IBOutlet connections. You have your storyboard set up to expect an outlet called distanceLabel but the actual outlet name is something else.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to get this error is to rename a variable after you connect an IBOutlet to it in the storyboard.

Step 1: Connect IBOutlet foo to a label.(Storyboard) .
Step 2: rename foo to fooLabel (Swift), without changing the storyboard.
Step 3: run app. crash with that error.

Like the chap in the comments says, give your IBOutlet connections a look.